# Display results of specific commands in bash script to screen

Tags: bash, osx-yosemite

In my script I am executing some git commands but I would like the output of the commands to display on the screen as the script runs.

OS X Yosemite, if that matters.

```
#!/bin/sh

# get the Git command from parameter
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
  echo "no arguments supplied"
  exit 1
fi
cmd=$1

echo "doing some stuff"
# do some stuff (not echoed to screen)

echo "executing command"
# this is the command I want to echo output to screen
git $cmd

echo "doing some other"
# do other stuff (not echoed to screen)
```

Comment: It should echo automatically.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen, you are correct.  The command I was using apparently had no output so I thought I was doing something wrong. TIL.

Comment: No output is something you get used to, if you use the command line enough. Haha.  ;^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff you don't want echoed to the screen can be redirected to `/dev/null` like so:

```
ls /tmp > /dev/null
```

The results of your `git` command will be echoed to the screen unless you've specifically said otherwise.

Comment: OMG you are right.  The command I was using for testing (git fetch) was showing nothing and I thought I was doing something wrong.  Sigh.  This is a great tip for not showing output.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `set -x` at the start of your script will print the commands before execution.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

# get the Git command from parameter
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
  echo "no arguments supplied"
  exit 1
fi

# ...
```

Comment: Helpful tip, but he's asking specifically about the output of the command, not the command itself.

Comment: @miken32 Right you are. My bad.

Comment: Title of the question is misleading in that sense, I think.